# É possivel gravar o que ocorre em um iframe em video?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível transformar o conteúdo de um iframe em vídeo, ou existe alguma linguagem que capture certa área de um site em vídeo?

resumidamente seria [isso](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/06/how-to-take-website-screen-shot-from-url-in-php.html) so que em forma de vídeo

- atualizacao: https://recordscreen.io/  << seria similar a isto

fico atento nas orientações dos colegas

Answer (score 3):

No front-end diretamente **NÃO** é possível sem depender de tecnologias extras, ou seja HTML+JavaScript+Canvas não é possível.

O que esse site recordscreen.io faz é captar a tela ou janela que o USUÁRIO permitir, usando [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia), para converter o canvas para um download (no formato de saída que o navegador suportar) pode usar o exemplo de https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('meu-canvas');

// Optional frames per second argument.
var stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
var recordedChunks = [];

var options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.start();

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  console.log("data-available");
  if (event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
    console.log(recordedChunks);
    download();
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
function download() {
  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: "video/webm"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "test.webm";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

// demo: to download after 9sec
setTimeout(event => {
  console.log("stopping");
  mediaRecorder.stop();
}, 9000);
```

Vale lembrar que a parte `canvas.captureStream(25)` é o que define também a taxa de FPS, 25 para a maioria das coisas web estará ótimo.

Um exemplo de captura de tela:

```js
function capturar()
{
    var configs = {
        video: true
    };

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(configs).then(capturando).catch(erro);
    } else if (navigator.getDisplayMedia) {
        // Navegadores antigos
        navigator.getDisplayMedia(configs).then(capturando).catch(erro);
    } else {
        erro("sem suporte")
    }

    function capturando()
    {
        console.log("capturando");
    }

    function erro(error)
    {
        console.log("erro", error);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="capturar()">Capturar</button>
```

E para colocar o vídeo no canvas (para poder fazer o processo de download depois (usando o `canvas.captureStream(25)`) use a própria API para desenhar em loop, mais ou menos assim:

```
var video = document.getElementById('meu-video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('meu-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

capturarVideo();

function capturarVideo()
{
    if (!video.paused && !video.ended) {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    setTimeout(capturarVideo, 1);
}
```

Claro que isso é um captura de tela e do ponto de vista funcional esse é o melhor meio de transmitir algo de forma decente, capturar elementos específicos é inviável, a não ser que use meios externos e talvez um programa próprio com um `webView` embarcado.

---

### As dificuldades que precisamos discutir sobre capturar elementos de páginas web

No site é dificil colocar um exemplo funcional porque o StackSnippet usa sandbox e pelo que testei algumas coisas ficam limitadas, portanto assim que possivel (se é que é necessário mesmo) irei ver um meio de colocar um exemplo online.

Você poderia até tentar adicionar o elemento do iframe no canvas e usar somente a parte do download do canvas com `canvas.captureStream(<fps>)`, ainda sim canvas tem limite para captura, existe até uma lib chamada **`html2canvas`**, que talvez alguém venha lhe citar no futuro, mas ele não captura de verdade a página ou elementos, é tudo simulado, é lento (é impossível ser mais rápido) e por isso não tem como usar para transformar em vídeo.